# Instance Points on Curve only at peaks and troughs Geometry Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, mathematics, instances

So im trying to attach ropes to this bridge at every peak and every trough, specifically everywhere the gradient of the curve is zero. Is it possible to calculate this in Blender so the ropes are only instanced at those points. And if so how could you make the count of points equal to the number of minimums and maximum in a given curve. I will attach my current node setup for the curves.
Thank you guys in advance.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can:

[image]

Resample curve and check each point if previous point and next both higher or lower

[image]